# How to vectorize this 2 loops in Pytorch (Difficult)

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization

How to vectorize this:

```
vocab_size = 20
batch_size = 2
input_len = 5
output_len = 10
input_ids = torch.randint(0, vocab_size, (batch_size, input_len))
output_ids = torch.randint(0, vocab_size, (batch_size, output_len))

print(input_ids)
print(output_ids)

tensor([[ 0,  8,  7, 12,  8],
        [14, 15,  9,  7, 10]])
tensor([[ 2, 8,  3, 15,  2, 19,  7,  1, 19,  8],
        [10,  8,  0,  7, 16,  0,  6,  2, 16, 13]])
```

Basically, the new value in output_ids gonna be batch_size + index of the k_th of that value in the input_ids because that value might appear multiple times in the input_ids and output_ids as well. So if that value appears for the second times in the output_ids, its' gonna be replace by vocab_size + the 2nd index of that value in the input_ids (Though my code above only get the first appearance). I change the value of output like an example (the 21 and 24 at the first row in the output)

This is what I want:

```
#%%
for i in range(batch_size):
    for k, value in enumerate(output_ids[i]):
        if value in input_ids[i] and value not in [0, 1, 2]: # mean that I will ignore values 0, 1, 2
            output_ids[i][k] = vocab_size + torch.where(input_ids[i] == value)[0][0]
output_ids

tensor([[ 2, 21,  3, 15,  2, 19, 22,  1, 19, 24],
        [24,  8,  0, 23, 16,  0,  6,  2, 16, 13]])
```

Comment: What should be done if a value appears twice in the `output_ids` but only once in the `input_ids`?

Comment: So the new value = batch_size + index of that value in the input_ids. Okay so more general it gonna be the latest appearance in the input_ids. I think you know what I mean (sorry for my eng) like it appear 3 times in output ids and 2 times in input_ids so. the value of the last 2 ones in output ids gonna have the same new value (get the index of the possible latest of input_ids)

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with this vertorization version, which is not optimized in term of memory because of the use of .clone()

```
output_ids_para = output_ids.clone()

## Equivalent to the reverse second condition of the if statement,
## that's why there is "~" notation below.
mask = (output_ids != 0) * (output_ids != 1) * (output_ids != 2)

## Replace with a value that does not appear in input_ids
output_ids_para[~mask] = vocab_size + 9999 

## Parallelize the comparison (first condition of the if statement + torch.where())
input_ids_expand = input_ids.unsqueeze(-1).expand(batch_size, input_len, output_len)
output_ids_expand = output_ids_para.unsqueeze(1).expand(batch_size, input_len, output_len)
indices_i, values, indices_k = torch.where(input_ids_expand == output_ids_expand) 

## Handle the duplicated values and indices
stacked, idx, counts =  torch.unique(torch.stack((indices_i, indices_k), dim = 1), dim =0, sorted=True, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
_, ind_sorted = torch.sort(idx, stable=True)
cum_sum = counts.cumsum(0)
cum_sum = torch.cat((torch.tensor([0]), cum_sum[:-1]))
first_indicies = ind_sorted[cum_sum]

indices_i, indices_k = indices_i[first_indicies], indices_k[first_indicies]
values = values[first_indicies]

## The newly assigned output_ids
output_ids_para[indices_i, indices_k] = vocab_size + values

## Return the value that does not satisfy the second condition of the if statement
output_ids_para[~mask] =  output_ids[~mask] 

output_ids_para
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I'll test your approach soon, but you might  want to check the above comment  as it give additional rules

Comment: The additional rule really complicates things up. You basically change `torch.where(input_ids[i] == value)[0]["0"]`  to `min(ocurrence, total_occurences)`, which I haven't seen a way to vectorize that.